# How come I got +4 rep points for a single post edit?

Tags: bug, status-planned, suggested-edits, reputation

I've been editing a post lately and after a while, I received +4 rep points for that edit.

I assumed +2 is the common rep gain for edits.

is there a special edit aspect that gives a +4?

**EDIT**

It seems (not guaranteed) that this scenario happens when you only add a tag to the edited post. Can the development team check this?

Comment: [Bug report on meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198697/can-a-user-gain-more-than-2-rep-for-editing) - The system will eventually realize it made a mistake and retract the additional +2, but we still don't know what causes this.

Comment: Seems you edited it twice. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24751779/revisions

Comment: @ShaunakD if you see the second revision is returning null, so edit was recorded twice so yea its a bug

Comment: @ShaunakD - nop, it is the same edit, but i assume it is the bug animuson is reporting about

Comment: The last two approves came in *at the exact same time* (at 07:00:31 UTC). I bet this happened on two different backend servers, so they both approved, saw the other approval recorded (after some deadlock breaking) and so both added the edit and gave you +2 points. A race condition.

Comment: About your edit, I "only added a tag" to a post few hours ago, got +2, not +4.

Comment: @ClémentMalet - as i said - it is *not guaranteed* - just trying to help the developer find the root cause. thanks for the comment

Comment: In 36 more points, it wont matter. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Does that imply a deadlock break in which neither was the victim? - or might that be the problem?

Comment: On a bit of a tangent - why remove the C++ tag from that question? It was the only valuable tag it had. Same for another edit suggested which removed visual-c++ (1.6k followers) and added visual-c++-2008 (6 followers).

Comment: @RobEarl: I agree; the OP should in fact have received +0 for this edit suggestion and had it rejected. I've restored sane tags.

Comment: @RobEarl - i would assume moving to a more specific tag will serve better to the OP - as he'll get more focus from specific members. I didn't pay attention to the number of followers. this is indeed another aspect to take into consideration. or should we cancel the visual-c++-2008 tag because it has only 6 followers and already covered by visual-c++?

Comment: @NirMH nope, use both. Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version

Comment: Whoever's trying to close this question, this should stay open. [**The problem is reproducible**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265677/how-come-i-got-4-rep-points-for-a-single-post-edit#comment61342_265677).

Answer (score 7):

I answered over on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321989/164200), but here is a copy:

> After a ton of digging through the database trying to identify how
> many users hit this bug and the cause of it, we've determined that
> it's a race condition.
>
> The fix will be going in this week, once we've identified all the places where we're hitting this same issue (Shog's got a list). The
> fix will include a redis lock (which we already use elsewhere), and it
> will prevent these very rare multiple entries.
>
> As far as the rep from these aka the extra +2, there are very few cases in which this happened and it involves deleting from several
> tables to clean it up, so we're leaving it. It shouldn't happen again
> after this week, when the bug is fixed.