# Should I not use the generic tag if my solution is limited to a specific version?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is related to a [previous question I have asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256723/1111886) where it was determined that if solutions must be limited to a specific version that is enough to use the version specific tag.

I had another question where the tag was removed. I noticed in the person who removed its description "I eat redundant tags", which caused me to think. Was the use of both the version specific and the general tag wrong?

I know from my earlier question the version specific is a correct usage, but when doing that should I not use the general tag? I understand it may be redundant but at the same time being in only the version tag severely limits my questions audience and my solution may not be exclusive to that version.

Comment: "if solutions must be limited to a specific version that is enough to use the version specific tag" -- wait, wut?  I provided the checked answer: all I said was to **use** [tag:C#-2.0] tag, not to **only use** [tag:C#-2.0]

Comment: @Yakk Right, you just said I should use that tag in that situation. You didn't really say anything on the generic tag nor did you have any reason to as it wasn't related to the scope of that question. It wasn't until I saw the comment in the persons profile that I even considered I might not want to use both. Now I'm wondering if there is even such a thing as "redundant tags" this person is so keen on removing. A tag is either applicable or not, regardless of other tags used.

Comment: [Related recent discussion about tag inheritance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262823/1238019)

Comment: Note: if you do *not* include the generic tag you reduce (by a lot) the number of users that can close your question as a duplicate using  [Mjölnir superpowers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212). This is bad since it means that a lot of bad duplicates will take much more time to be closed.

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't matter what you do, the robo editors and reviewers will cyclically add and remove them to farm rep and badges.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You'd be better off still including the generic tag; the generic tag serves to attract the domain experts, the version-specific tag to communicate that the problem is version specific.

Take Python for example; version specific tags, even for the current versions, have a limited number of followers:

- [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x): 66 followers
- [python-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6): 40 followers
- [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7): 2.4k followers
- [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x): 2.3k followers
- [python-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.3): 75 followers
- [python-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.4): 60 followers

while [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) has 45k people following it, over 20 times the next most numerous version-specific tag.

We really appreciate it when a user uses the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag for Python 3-specific issues, for example, but I always add [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to such questions if it is missing.

Comment: This is what I thought, but when a user with 67k reputation seems committed to the opposite you question yourself.

Comment: @Fr33dan: this is a community, there will always people that disagree with the consensus. It may be that I turn out to be such a person, for that matter; if someone posts the opposite view here and that gets more upvotes than my answer, I'll have to eat my hat, I suppose!

Comment: Indeed, that is why I have only given you an upvote and not marked the answer yet. I'd like to hear from someone with the opposite view but I can at least give them time to weigh in.

Comment: The generic tags get many more views in my experience in the Oracle area. Something *only* tagged Oracle11g tends to have low views, so I'll sometimes add the generic tag to a question I find so others can find it more easily. The [tag wiki for Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) actually says the generic tag should be used too; not sure if that's generally the case. (I'm wary of retagging after answering as it looks a bit dodgy sometimes...)

Comment: @AlexPoole: The Python tag does the same.

Comment: it seems like `python-3.3` should imply `python-3.x` and both should imply `python`. since the system doesn't work that way, having more than one of them ends up not actually being redundant.

Comment: @Sahuagin Maybe the system should work that way...

Comment: Yet another "for" argument: If you have the generic tag selected as a favourite one, only questions with it are highlighted in the list, questions marked with only a version-specific tag do not.

Comment: I was wondering if specific tags like `python-2.6` could automatically have added the more generic tag like `python`, this would save some manual re-tagging

Comment: @Chris_Rands: there is no auto-tagging functionality at the moment.