# merge request: [jquery-datatables] and [datatables]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[jquery-datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) and [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) tags reference the same thing. They have the same description, one has 4k questions tagged, the other 2k. I think datatables should become an alias for jquery-datatables.

[image: The two tags appearing in the tag dropdown]

Comment: Side note: why is DataTables 1.10 special?

Comment: I think it was a major release with a fair amount of features/api differences than there were previously, but I don't think thats enough to merit its own tag

Comment: If it was a major release, then [having the versioned tag might make sense](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version).

Comment: only ~1% of questions are tagged with it though

Comment: @rene thanks. After reading that, it looks like they were still undecided about what to do? Is there still an opinion they should not be merged?

Comment: @chiliNUT It looks like the general consensus over there is to merge the tags (leaving [tag:jquery-datatables]), which only a mod can do.  This might be because the tag wasn't cleaned up at all, and merging might mean including questions with bad tags.

Comment: and going thru 4000 datatables questions seems a little rough... I suppose I'll start cleaning those up a few at a time when it occurs to me