# Usefulness of the [Python-3.x] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

As the use of Python3 becomes more widespread and Python2 approaches its EOL, I find the use of the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag being less and less relevant and more synonymous with the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.

I wonder if it would be prudent to make the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag a synonym for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). My hunch is the answer is 'no' here, but I'm interested in the reasoning there.

I was also thinking it may be useful if we update the [tagging recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) for both tags. My suggestion would be that we only encourage the use of the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag when version is central to the question. That is to say, just because the content *happens* to include some python3-specific feature, doesn't mean it should necessarily be tagged [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).
I feel with this stricter guideline, the tag would have a more useful distinction from questions simply tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Comment: Your hunch is correct. No, it does not need to be a synonym. It's use will just fade, just like the `python-2.x` tag is little used today.

Comment: I think `[python-3.x]` is certainly useful to indicate Python 3 specific issues, but yes `[python]` tag should also be present, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364993/gold-dupehammer-after-updating-tags-with-generic-language-tag and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version

Comment: Makes sense. I guess what I feel is that the `python-3.x` tag is overused, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate to remove it some cases. For example, a python3-specific feature might be used, but the core concept of the question really isn't version-specific. Especially given that python2 will fall out of use, there's hardly a distinction being made when people use the `python-3.x` tag today.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions that the generic [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag cannot cover, because they are specifically related to Python 3.  If so the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag becomes necessary.

Answer (score -5):

No.  At present there are two versions of Python.  Python 2 and 3.  At the moment the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (along with the [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)) tag is often necessary to distinguish between the syntaxes.

By 2020 Python 2 will be obsolete, no longer used and it will be likely the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) will become a tag synonym. Until Python 4 is released, in which case it will still be necessary.

Comment: I don't think in 2020 `[python-3.x]` well become a synonym, python 2 will still be used, people are still using python 2.6 now, and asking questions, despite it's age

Comment: @Chris_Rands  But that is the EOL date for Python 2, so I can't see people using it.  Second Python 4 may be introduced in which case once again, differentiating the code will be important.

Comment: Well, my assertion is that, new questions will largely be using Python3; that it's now the 'norm'. Many questions are only tagged `python` but use python3-specific features, and answers can only work in Python3 and nobody will pipe up anymore and say "hey that doesn't work in python2". Python3 is virtually assumed unless stated (or tagged) otherwise... So if it's not tagged `python-2.x` it should be safe to say it's Python3, somewhat obsoleting the need for the `python-3.x` tag in my view. I see it more useful as tagging for issues that, at the core, are version-related.

Comment: There is no need to make it a synonym. It should not be. And Python 2 support ending doesn’t mean the questions will end or that old posts don’t deserve being properly tagged.

Comment: And 2020 is the date the Python code devs stop the Python 2.7 updates and releases; a third party is still free to provide support beyond that date.