# Does looking under the python tag also show posts under the python-x.x tag?

Tags: support, tags

I like to browse through questions when I'm bored and am just wondering if I'm only seeing questions marked strictly as python or if the python tag will also show posts labeled as python-x.x

If not, is there a way to browse all python tags at once?

I suppose a simple way to word this: Is the python tag a catch all for subsequent python tags

Comment: Search for [python-*]

Comment: @rene: that misses out plain `python`, still very usual to find as the only language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why did you just not try that? Spoiler:

> It does not.

2. Search for, or add to your favorite tags: `[python*]`. It expands in the search field to the rather long expression

> [python] or [python-3.x] or [python-2.7] or [python-requests] or [python-imaging-library] or [python-3.5] or [python-3.4] or [python-import] or [python-3.6] or [python-sphinx] or [python-2.x] or [python-multiprocessing] or [python-multithreading] or [python-asyncio] or [python-unittest] or [python-2.6] or [python-3.3] or [python-module] or [python-idle] or [python-decorators]

but fortunately it does not do that in favorite tags.

It has been proposed a few times to make `python` a [synonym of the latest version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365015/2564301), but there are good arguments against that.

Comment: Oh this is lovely. Are there any other customization for searches outlined somewhere? I don't recall that being mentioned in the tour.

Comment: @akozi: but it did mention there is a Help Center  If you enter anything in the Search field, to its right is a button "Advanced search tips", which shows a shortlist of most common operations, and a further link to [its own Help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).